# Does testing through ProgramTestContext have any disadvantage over `solana-test-validator`?

Tags: testing, solana-test-validator, program-test

`solana-test-validator` is basically a full validator run locally.
`ProgramTestContext` looks more light-weight.
Does testing through `ProgramTestContext` skip any checks compared to `solana-test-validator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`solana-program-test` uses the same runtime as `solana-test-validator`, with a few differences:

- solana-program-test gives you a `BanksClient` rather than an `RpcClient`, which has a bit less functionality
- solana-test-validator constantly moves slots forward, whereas `ProgramTestContext` is locked to a slot until you use `warp_to_slot()`. This means that you have control over time with `ProgramTestContext`

As an on-chain program developer, you don't need to worry about any differences between the two, other than these.